# Whats is the difference between using '@aws-sdk/client-sqs' and 'aws-sdk/clients/sqs'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-nodejs

There are a few differences between the packages `@aws-sdk/client-sqs` and `aws-sdk/clients/sqs` in terms of declaration, but what about the functionalities? Is there a single implication choosing any of them?

**Using `@aws-sdk/client-sqs`:**

```
import { SQSClient, ListQueuesCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-sqs';

export default class SQSHelper {
    client: SQSClient;

    constructor(region: string) {
        this.client = new SQSClient({ region });
    }

    listQueues() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.client.send(new ListQueuesCommand({}), (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        }
        );
    }
}
```

**Using `aws-sdk/clients/sqs`:**

```
import SQSClient from 'aws-sdk/clients/sqs';

export default class SQSHelper {
    client: SQSClient;

    constructor(region: string) {
        this.client = new SQSClient({ region });
    }

    listQueues() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.client.listQueues({}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`@aws-sdk/client-sqs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sqs/index.html) is part of version 3 of AWS JavaScript SDK. [`aws-sdk/clients/sqs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html) is part of V2 JavaScript SDK.

As of today, you can use V2 SDK in Lambda without adding any additional dependencies to your Lambda package or without creating a new Lambda Layer. Most likely, this kind of support will happen for V3 in the future.

Answer (score 1):

SDK v3 versus v2.  `@aws-sdk/client-sqs` is part of [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html).  Client packages are modular in v3, which is now in GA.  `aws-sdk/clients/sqs` is from v2, which included all clients in one big package.